# Change of pdf files name in powershell

Tags: powershell

This is the 3rd time i am facing a situation. I need to change the name of fiels, around 10,000. thes are pdf files with name like 101SG1058_SH2_R2F2.pdf. i just want to delete the first three number in this case 101. 
the folder having these files is located at C:\All

So i tried to look, the web answers, they are good. but i never ever used powershell or command prompt. so can someone tells me, how to do it.
in the same way if i need to add two letter in the name somehere, how it can be done.
By the way i am using win 7.

Regards

Nadeem

Comment: What solutions did you find? What problems did you have implementing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the -replace operator together with a regular expression p[attern to remove all digits from the start of the file name:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\All -Filter *.pdf | 
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '^\d+'}
```

Comment: Thanks Shay, I am getting the following error,PS C:\all> Get-ChildItem -Path C:\All -Filter *.pdf | 
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '^\d+'}

Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

At line:2 char:12
+ Rename-Item <<<<  -NewName {$_.Name -replace '^\d+'}
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\All\002_SH1_R2A.pdf:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: It appears that the new file name (without leading digits already exits). The new file name should be unique otherwise you'll get this kind of errors.

Comment: By the way what is mean by last term '^\d+'

Comment: ^ denotes the start of the string, \d digits and the plus sign means one digit or more. The pattern should match one or more digits from the start of string.

Comment: @ShayLevy -- how can you purposefully rename and overwrite and existing file of the same name in the same directory?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, haven't been here for a while. I didn't test it nut what if you add the Force switch?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the quick solution is like this:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\All | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('101','') }
```

Just posted here because you write that you have never used powershell or command prompt.
Anyway, you should try yourself - check the other scripts and you will see some patterns like `Get-ChildItem ...` repeating over and over. Then look at what that means. The same with `Rename-Item`.

If you have Total Commander next time you can try `CTRL+M` - it opens *multi-rename tool*. Very useful, used it a lot of times.

Invest your time into learning, it pays off.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I posted my problem  afetr spending around 3 hours. I never ever worked with computer codes so was not able to understand what these signs mean. for now its over, but i will spend some more time to it.